# How do you enable 32 binary compatability in JDK?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, 64-bit, java

Is there a vm option option to enable 32bit compatibility mode?

I've googled but couldn't find how to do it anywhere!

The reason I am doing it is I'm trying to run the GWT on Linux Ubuntu 64 as the link below indicates is possible.

[Issue 134:      GWT hosted web browser does not work in 64-bit Linux](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=134)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sun 1.6 JVM does not have an option to enable 32bit mode. You can however install a 32bit JVM along side the install of the 64bit JVM.

Comment: blood glucose low, eclipse configuration file was set to use system default (64 bit) instead of 32 bit preference in eclipse

Answer (score 2):

You mean run the JVM as a 32-bit JVM? Try -d32 on the command line.

Comment: Thanks, I though that was thr option, but I had tried that, added both to eclipse.ini and to the installed jre being used in eclipse, still gives same error, I think there may be something else missing from my configuration

Comment: blood glucose low, eclipse configuration file was set to use system default (64 bit) instead of 32 bit preference in eclipse